# Encryption and Decryption method in Axis Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, parameters, cryptography, axis

I want to ask a question regarding the Axis Web Service. As my class `KeyManager` and its method `Encryption` with parameter of `byte[]` and `Key` which is already been deployed on Axis, then I don't know how to call the web service because there is one line of code in java asks me to specify their type, and I couldn't find.

As follows:

```
call.addParameter(parameterName,parameterType,Parameter.in/out);
```

Who can tell what are the types I should put for my `byte[]` parameter and Key parameter, so that I can call that web service?

Code to call the web service:

public static String encryptID() throws Exception{

```
Service service = new Service();

   Call call = (Call) service.createCall();

   call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new   
       java.net.URL("http://10.20.172.58:9099/axis2/services/KeyManager?wsdl"));
   call.setOperationName(new QName("http://IVTpinService","Encryption"));
   call.addParameter("plainText", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
   call.addParameter("", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);

   call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);

      String pbid = (String) call.invoke(new Object[]{});

   return pbid;
```

}

Comment: the question is very ambiguous unless further code provided

Comment: //Function to do the encryptionprivate static byte[] Encryption(byte[] plainText, Key ekey) throws Exception{

  Cipher cipher = InitializeCipher(ekey.getAlgorithm());
  if(ekey.getAlgorithm()=="AES"){
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ekey, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
  }else{
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ekey);
  }

  byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);

  return cipherText;

Comment: this method has already been deployed on Axis , now I wanna try to call this web service/method using java.

Comment: Davy, that's still pretty unclear. Please define *what* you are trying to achieve more precisely. Don't put code into comments. Try and refrain from youtube style language. Furthermore, there are several mistakes in the code you provided (using just `"AES"` as algorithm, using `==` instead of `equals` for Strings and the `if` statement itself does not make sense either).

Comment: I deploy that method on Axis Web Service , what I am trying to get is that I wanna call the web service abovementioned using java.